# Editing full objectlist through Index page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to be able to press a submit button in my Index view which saves all the changes made to the list through the EditorFors that I use.

In the Edit View I can edit and save one list item at a time, but I would like to be able to save the full list in one click.

I've tried wrapping the whole table in the Index view with `@using(Html.BeginForm()) {}`, then added an HttpPost method in the controller like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<TileModel> modelList) {

        return View(modelList);
    }
```

But `modelList` is null when I enter this method. I've tried adding `[Bind("MyModel")]` to the parameter list but I'm a bit clueless as what to bind ..

I'm basically trying to copy the functionality of this:

```
  [HttpPost] 
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Name,Employment")] TileModel mModel) {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) {
            db.Entry(mModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(mModel);
    }
```

, but have it save the full list while inside the Index view.

Any ideas how one could achieve this? Am I even remotely on the right track?

Edit:

Here's my index view(my edit view is basically unchanged from what visual studio generates so I don't think it's that interesting to show?).

```
@model IEnumerable<Anslagstavlan.Models.TileModel>
@{ ViewBag.Title = "title"; }

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("TILES", "tileboard", "tilemodels")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("NEW ENTRY", "Create")</li>
</ul>

@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name) </th>
        <th>  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InfoFields)  </th>
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employment) </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach(var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>   @Html.DisplayFor(mItem => item.Name)   </td>
                <td>  @Html.EditorFor(mItem => item.InfoFields, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) </td>
                <td>  @Html.DisplayFor(mItem => item.Employment) </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("SAVE", "Save", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("EDIT", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) 
                </td>
            </tr>
    }
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

Edit2, working:

My loop with the table now looks like:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    <table class="table">
        @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
        <tr> <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Name)
        </td> </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

The only difference from Stephens answer is the @ sign before the for loop..

Comment: Your method needs to be `IEnumerable<MyModel> model` (and no `[Bind]` attribute) - but you need to show your view.

Comment: Your view wont ind to anything on post back. You need to use a `for` loop (not `foreach`) so the controls are correctly named with indexers. And the only property you are posting back is `InfoFields` (if you need the other properties, you need controls for them as well). Then change the POST method as per my first comment (and of course remove the actin links for edit and save)

Comment: Do you mean like " for(int i...) Model.ElementAt(i)..." or in some other way that I'm not aware of? It still doesn't work ..

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InfoFields) }` and the model needs to be `IList`, not `IEnumerable`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm starting to feel a bit stupid here, but I really can't get it to work .. `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) }` gives an error "the type cannot be inferred from the usage" 
and something like 
`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Name)` doesn't work because I Model is IEnumerable! 

(sorry haha, enter posts the comment when I wanted newline)

Comment: I'll post an answer shortly (sorry my last comment should have been `m => m[i].InfoFields)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the model in the view to be `IList<TileModel>` and generate the controls in a `for` loop so they are correctly named with indexers and can be bound to a collection on post back

View

```
@model IList<Anslagstavlan.Models.TileModel>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].InfoFields, new { @class = "form-control" })
    .... // controls for other properties of your model that you want to post back
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<TileModel> modelList)
{
  // save each item and redirect
}
```

Comment: Code looks aweful in comments. Edited my post instead .. :P Thanks a lot!

Comment: Whether the `@` is required or not depends on where the `for` is rendered. In my example it works fine (adding the `@` would generate an error). In your example you needed it because you have another container - the `<table>` element - separating `BeginForm` from the `for` loop